# Add Repositories give following error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: repository

```
:-$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 91, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for UberStudent/socrates
```

Comment: What happens when you try to add the repository manually [following these directions](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/apps)?  Click the Arrow next to the Green Text

Comment: Does sudo apt-get update work?  FWIW, I added the repo without problem.